# Getting Error: Using PythonUDF in join condition of join type LeftSemi is not supported

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, aws-databricks

I have a pypark.sql Dataframe which was created using an inner join of two data frames. I have also created one column after joining which provides week_start date based on the date.

```
Joined_data=Joined_data.withColumn("Week_start_date",date_sub(next_day('AsOfDate','Sun'),7))
```

Now, when I want to create a list(collection) of all week. I am using the below code.

```
DateList=Joined_data.select('Week_start_date').dropDuplicates()
```

I am getting the Error: **"Using PythonUDF in join condition of join type LeftSemi is not supported."**

If I remove dropDuplicates() method from the above line it runs fine without any error.

Does anyone have any idea why I am getting this error with dropDuplicates() method?